# Multiple Nested Recyclerviews Slow Downs App Performance

Tags: java, android

- Image Caching Library :- Glide
- Network Request Library :- Retrofit
- I am also using "recyclerview.setnestedscrollingenabled()" method.

-**If anyone has other programming language option please tell me.**
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Use shared `RecyclerViewPool` between your `RecyclerViews`, it might be help in this situation but still it will make issue due to **nested scrolling enabled**.

Comment: There can be many reasons that can contribute to slowness. Follow this https://developer.android.com/studio/profile and check which is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

When the user swipes the side-wise the inner RecyclerView recycles the views and gives you a smooth scroll. But this is not the case when the user scrolls vertically. Each of the views of the inner RecyclerView is inflated again. This is because each of the nested RecyclerViews has a view pool of its own. We can fix this by setting a single view pool for all the inner RecyclerViews.

```
RecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(RecycledViewPool)
```

RecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(RecycledViewPool) allows you to set a custom view pool to your recyclerView. The code looks like this

```
public OuterRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Item> items) {
    //Constructor stuff
    viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Create viewHolder etc
    holder.innerRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);

}
```

Comment: i want to make view like "MxPlayer Online Section".They load multiple recyclerviews without hanging UI.

Comment: Ok. Here is the complete example of this http://khmertechtrain.tk/index.php/2017/10/03/create-a-vertical-scroll-and-horizontal-scroll-app-like-google-play-store/

Comment: Thank You Shivam. I am also created view like Google Play Store but problem is view is lagging on scroll when app start.It is not smooth like other apps.